# Hibernate does not throw an exception on duplicate primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working with Spring Data JPA. Given this setup:

```
@Entity
public class Role
{
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String info;
}

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, String>
{
}
```

I can simply insert a `Role` with the same primary key (`name`) twice. It justs updates the entry in the database. I would like it to throw an exception though. Trying to insert two entries with the same primary key at database-level gives the desired "duplicate key"-error.

---

## Example:

Role table is empty

```
MariaDB [logz]> select * from role;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Saving the first time

```
roleRepository.save(new Role("name1", "info0"));
```

Hibernate first checking, then saving

```
Hibernate: select role0_.name as name1_3_0_, role0_.info as info2_3_0_ from role role0_ where role0_.name=?
Hibernate: insert into role (info, name) values (?, ?)
```

Role table is filled

```
MariaDB [logz]> select * from role;
+-------+-------+
| name  | info  |
+-------+-------+
| name1 | info0 |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Saving the second time

```
roleRepository.save(new Role("name1", "info1"));
```

Hibernate checking and updating - I want an exception here though!

```
Hibernate: select role0_.name as name1_3_0_, role0_.info as info2_3_0_ from role role0_ where role0_.name=?
Hibernate: update role set info=? where name=?
```

Role table is simply updated :(

```
MariaDB [logz]> select * from role;
+-------+-------+
| name  | info  |
+-------+-------+
| name1 | info1 |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of the save method it is like this:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

so you can notice that it will do update in case an object with a particular id is already present in the database. If you are further interested you can find the source [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java).

Comment: But do you have any advice on how to address the problem now? I mean when for example creating a User, I don't accidentally want to "overwrite" (merge) a new User into an existing one. Do I really have to check for an existing entry every time before I insert it?

Comment: You shouldn't be generating ids manually. For that matter you shouldn't even use String for id probably. You have to define a strategy (maybe a sequence) which the ORM provider will use to assign ids.

Comment: But I'd like to use a natural primary key. Is that wrong? Should I just use a synthetic key and mark my column (that was my natural primary key before) as unique?

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox If you handle the uniqueness of the key yourself you can do it , yes.